# Only do LF (line feed) at the end of print in python

Tags: python, windows

When ever I do print 'some text' with a Windows interpreter of Python, it always adds CRLF at the end of each line. I tried doing "print 'some text\n'," but it always puts CRLF when I just want to do LF. Is there a way to just do LF at the end of print within Python 2.7?

Comment: You shouldn't be able to tell in a terminal. If you are printing to a file, open it 'wb' instead of 'w'.

Comment: @nneonneo: actually, you can switch Windows stdout to binary mode.

Comment: _"it always puts CRLF when I just want to do LF."_ I'm curious. How can you tell?

Comment: What I'm doing is sending the output to a file (python print.py > printed.txt) and then I'm just viewing it in notepad++

Comment: @RyanMcClelland: you could just open a file object explicitly and write to that instead of redirecting stdout. At that point you have far more control over how newlines are handled.

Answer (score 3):

`print` adds an implicit newline, always. And writing just a `\n` newline is translated to your platform default line separator; on Windows writing a `\n` is translated to `\r\n` for you.

If you wanted to write just a line feed without the carriage return, you'll have to switch stdout in binary mode:

```
import msvcrt, os, sys
msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdout.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)
```

Now newlines will no longer be translated for you.

Comment: Why would printing Unicode objects fail? Python doesn't know about setmode's value, and the translation seems to affect only line endings.

Comment: @nneonneo: ah, excellent point. I was noting that the [writing code only encodes Unicode when in binary mode](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3f73c44b1fd1/Objects/fileobject.c#l1813) but failed to think this through. The `binary` flag is not set to false here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use \r\n for a line ending on Windows environment.

Comment: But this writes a `CRLF` too, not just a `LF`.